# Aggregating data based on first column values

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, aggregate

I would like to know how to aggregate data based on the first column. Here's an exmple:

My current data in matrix:

```
c1
1  1 2 3 4 5 6
1  1 2 3 4 5 6
1  1 2 3 4 5 6
2  1 2 3 4 5 6
3  1 2 3 4 5 6
3  1 2 3 4 5 6
```

result data:

```
c1
1  3 6 9 12 15 18
2  1 2 3 4  5  6
3  2 4 6 8  10 12
```

Do you know any good functions?

Comment: Will the first column always contain positive integer values? Will they always be consecutive, sorted, and starting from 1?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) as follows:

```
c1 = [1  1 2 3 4 5 6
      1  1 2 3 4 5 6
      1  1 2 3 4 5 6
      2  1 2 3 4 5 6
      3  1 2 3 4 5 6
      3  1 2 3 4 5 6]; % data
[u, ~, w] = unique(c1(:,1)); % u: unique elements; w: integer that indicates the group
result = [u splitapply(@(x)sum(x,1), c1(:,2:end), w)]; % sum over 1st dim within a group
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

1. Find all unique indices from the first column using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).
2. Then I use [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to sum all rows for a specific index. Sometimes, `arrayfun` is perceived as some loop in disguise, so looping would be fine, too. (See also [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) and [find array elements that meet a condition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html).)
3. At last, I set up the desired output format.

Please see the following code:

```matlab
% Input data.
c1 = [
  1 1 2 3 4 5 6
  1 1 2 3 4 5 6
  1 1 2 3 4 5 6
  2 1 2 3 4 5 6
  3 1 2 3 4 5 6
  3 1 2 3 4 5 6
]

% Get unique indices from first column.
idx = unique(c1(:, 1));

% For all unique indices calculate sum over all rows with specified index.
result = arrayfun(@(x) sum(c1((c1(:, 1) == x), 2:end), 1), idx, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Set up proper output.
result = [idx, vertcat(result{:})]


c1 =
   1   1   2   3   4   5   6
   1   1   2   3   4   5   6
   1   1   2   3   4   5   6
   2   1   2   3   4   5   6
   3   1   2   3   4   5   6
   3   1   2   3   4   5   6

result =
    1    3    6    9   12   15   18
    2    1    2    3    4    5    6
    3    2    4    6    8   10   12
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using linear algeabra:

```
% Example data
c1  = [1 1 2 3 4 5 6
       1 1 2 3 4 5 6
       1 1 2 3 4 5 6
       2 1 2 3 4 5 6
       3 1 2 3 4 5 6
       3 1 2 3 4 5 6]

% We split the c1 matrix in two parts and calculate its size along the first dimension
A = c1(:,1);
B = c1(:,2:end);
n = size(c1,1);

% We can use sparse(A,1:n,1) to create our matrix:
% sparse([1 1 1 0 0 0
%         0 0 0 1 0 0
%         0 0 0 0 1 1])
% Then using a matrix multiplication we obtain the result:
res  = sparse(A,1:n,1)*B

%If you want to preserve the indices
%res= [[1:max(A(:,1))].',sparse(A,1:n,1)*B]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a few unique numbers in the first column of the input data, then, I would prefer following code

```
c1 = [1  1 2 3 4 5 6
1  1 2 3 4 5 6
1  1 2 3 4 5 6
2  1 2 3 4 5 6
3  1 2 3 4 5 6
3  1 2 3 4 5 6];

uidx= unique(c1(:,1));

c2= zeros(length(uidx), size(c1,2));

for ii = 1:length(uidx)
   idx = (c1(:,1)==uidx(ii));
   c2(ii,:) = [uidx(ii) sum(c1(idx,2:end),1)];
end

disp(c2)
     1     3     6     9    12    15    18
     2     1     2     3     4     5     6
     3     2     4     6     8    10    12
```